# Unable to make the addition 17 + 54 on Mips the result is always G. Any idea how to solve it?

Tags: mips

I am trying to add up 2 variables but the result is always G.

Tried playing with the code but the result is never the addition of the 2 numbers, the result is always G see:

```
.data
variable1: .word 17
variable2: .word 54
variable3: .word 0

.text
main:

lw $t0, variable1
lw $t1, variable2
add $t2, $t0, $t1
sw $t2, variable3
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0, variable3
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Syscall 4 is "print string". Do you really want to print a string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: 17 plus 54 *is* G.

Based on Raymond Chen's comment, syscall 4 is "print string." You're passing the syscall a pointer to variable 3, which, in memory, looks like this:

```
 0x47 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

By pure coincidence, `0x47` is the ASCII code for G, and 0 is the null terminator. The other two zero bytes are ignored by the print syscall, since it reads each byte one at a time, starting from the address you gave it, until a 0 is read. Therefore, as far as the CPU is concerned, the string `"G"` and the number `0x00000047` are one and the same. The syscall takes whatever is at that address and interprets it as a string (in this case) which is why you get G.

(From this error, I can also tell you're using a <del>big</del> little-endian architecture. If you weren't, your output would appear to be empty!)

Edit: Wrong endian!

Comment: (Actually, little-endian. 0x47 is the least-order byte, and it came first.)